# Conversion from char * to wchar* does not work properly

Tags: c++, wstring, wchar, fedora12

I'm getting a string like: `"aña!a¡a¿a?a"` from the server so I decode it and then I pass it to a function.

What I need to do with the message is something like loading paths depending the letters.

The header of my function is: `void SetInfo(int num, char *descr[4])` so it receives one number and an array of 4 chars (sentences). To make it easier, let's say I just need to work only with descr[0].

When I debug and arrive there to SetInfo(), I get the exact message in the debugg view: `"aña!a¡a¿a?a"` so until here is all ok. 
Initially, the info I was receiving on that function, was a std::wstring so all my code working with that message was with wstrings and strings but now what I receive is a char as shown in the header. The message arrived until here ok, but if I want to work with it, then I can't because if I debug and see each position of Descr[0] then I get

```
 descr[0][0] = 'a'; //ok
 descr[0][1] = 'Ã '; // BAD
```

so I tried converting char* to wchar* with a code found here:

```
 size_t size = strlen(descr[0]) + 1;
 wchar_t* wa = new wchar_t[size];
 mbstowcs(wa,descr[0],size);
```

But then the debugger shows me that `wa` has:

`wa wchar_t *   0x185d4be8 L"a-\uffffffff刯2e2e牵6365⽳6f73歯6f4c楲6553䈯736f獵6e6f档6946琯7361灭6569湰2e6f琀0067\021ᡰ9740슃b8\020\210=r"`

which I suppose that is incorrect (I'm supossing that I have to see the same initial message of `"aña!a¡a¿a?a"`. If this message is fine then I don't know how to get what I need...)

So my question is: how can I get that descr[0][0] = 'a' and descr[0][1] = 'ñ' ?? I can't pass char to wchar (you've already see what I got). Am I doing it wrong? Or is there any other way? I am really stuck on that so any idea will be very apreciated.

Before, when I was working with wstrings (and it worked so fine) I was doing something like this:

```
if (word[i]==L'\x00D1' or word[i]==L'\x00F1')  // ñ or Ñ
   path ="PathOfÑ";
```

where word[i] is the same as descr[0][1] in that case but with wstrings. So with that i knew that this word[i] was the letter 'ñ'. Maybe this helps to understand what I'm doing

(btw...I'm working on eclipse, on linux. )

Comment: Is fixed-size character buffers really the right way to do this in C++? Why not use `std::wstring`?

Comment: This really needs more information. Why are you even using `char`? If I understand the information correctly, you could simply read `wchar_t` string and be done with it. No need for parsing.

Comment: In many implementations, there's an extension to the [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) function which allows it to tell you the length of the destination. Use it to get the *actual* length of the destination string.

Comment: `wchar_t[size]` is fixed, though the length it's fixed at is dynamic. `std::wstring` and friends are dynamic length. You'll never have a buffer overflow problem if you use them correctly.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be the thing is that when I decode ( and i have to do it this way,    no other possibility) the decode function gaves me a char* so I pass that char to my function to work with it

Comment: @tadman ohhh sorry my fault, though you were talking about another thing. That was an example taken from internet and it worked so I let it as it is for the moment. What do you say I have to do then? I don't get how to change it. can you post the code?

Comment: @Megasa3 And what exactly does this "decode" function do with the input?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be well for example I have to declare a char text[21], then use decodestring(text, 20); so I have the info in text and then adds a \0

Comment: @Megasa3 But what does `decodestring` do with the content? You need to "undo" that in your code. In what encoding are you getting the input? What encoding is the input in after it is passed through `decodestring`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I asked my boss many times about that and he doesn't really know (and is the one who should, nice thinkg) but i know that i can receive and get fine things like ñ, á é Ï but not the € sign... so that is all I have to work with ...

Comment: @Megasa3 Well, then look at the binary values you are getting and use the official UTF encoding tables to to determine what kind of encoding you are getting. From there, it should be pretty trivial to recode the `char*` into `wchar_t` and use native functions from there.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be When I debug, if the text is "aña" and I put descr[0][1] in the debugger, it says that is a char type and the value is `-61 'Ã'` ... is that what you are asking for? Other examples: `E = 69 'E'` , `u = 117 'u'` Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) function work on C-style strings, and one of the things about C-style strings is that they have a special terminating character, `'\0'`. You don't seem to be adding this terminator to the string, leading `mbstowcs` to go out of bounds of the actual string and giving you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I missed that \0 in my example but still I get that: `L"a-\uffffffff刯2e2e牵6365⽳6f73歯6f4c楲6553䈯736f獵6e6f档6946琯7361灭6569湰2e6f琀0067\021ᡰ9740슃b8\020\210=r"`