# c++: Decoding with mbtowsc() not working with special characters

Tags: c++, eclipse, decode, fedora, wchar-t

After learning a lot of things from that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568110/conversion-from-char-to-wchar-does-not-work-properly) (to sum up: I need to decode special characters as 'ñ' in eclipse on a fedora), now I see that I was doing it wrong or at least that is what I think because I was decoding the text as a normal string and then trying to pass it from char to wchar_t and now I'm using mbtowsc() to decode it from the beggining. So now....I have another couple of doubts/problems.

**What I have:**
A server sends me the text `"$ Euroñ $"`(which I don't know how is it encoded, just that the string is encoded as  ANSI 1 byte). I load that text in descr[0], so when I debug it, some values are:

```
descr[0][2]= 69 'E'
descr[0][3]= 117 'u'
descr[0][4]= 114 'r'
descr[0][5]= 111 'o'
descr[0][6]= -15 'ñ'
```

With that, I suppose you can know if it is utf-8 or not, which I suppose it is.

My goal is to be able to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    if(descr[0][i]=='a') //do things
    else if (descr[0][i]=='ñ') // do other stuff  
}
```

This is what I am not able to get because ofc descr[0][6] never equals 'ñ'...

I've tried with:

```
   if(descr[0][i]=='\x00D1')
   if(descr[0][i]=='\x00F1')
   if(descr[0][i]=='ñ') //this compiles but then ignores that if like it is an error
   if(descr[0][i]==L'ñ')
```

But it never enters on any of that ifs, so.. to what should I compare descr[0][i] to know if it is an 'ñ' ?

Thanks.

Comment: When you decode bytes into Unicode, you *need* to know which encoding it's in, you can't just assume. If you assume wrong you get garbage.

Comment: @MarkRansom finally i got an answer from the guy who encode it. He sais that he takes all the string ("$ Euroñ $") and uses a function that encodes it entirely and he says that is ANSI 1 byte.... but he doesn't know which codepage uses or anything else.

Comment: The symptoms you describe with your last edit suggest that the conversion function is exiting on bad input and leaving the end of your buffer uninitialized, in particular it's missing the ending `\0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Mmm.... but he is sending it as any other normal string, which are encoded and decoded fine so.. its really extrange for me to hear that unless it is something about the special chars

Comment: What is the rest of the string? You stop at `descr[0][6]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've changed the question... appareantly the person on the server changed the text and didn't told me....  -.-'' now that he really sends the 'ñ', I get it fine as a `-15 'ñ' ` But I can never equal it (see my question again as I changed it please). Any idea of why and what should I do?

Comment: `-15` is the same byte as `0xf1`, which is `ñ` in the [ISO-8859-1 code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). That's what I'd try for decoding to Unicode.